# ServiceLocationProvider is null when launched as a Share Target

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light

I'm using MVVM Light and everything is fine except when launching my Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT app as a Share Target.

When I try to assign `MainViewModel viewModel = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();` I get an exception for ServiceLocator.Current.

**Exception Message: ServiceLocationProvider must be set.**

Do I need to do something extra in App.xaml.cs OnShareTargetActivated event to insure the Locator is running?

UPDATE:
A ShareTarget page needs to be thought of as a small extension of your app. It seems that not all of the app's resources are loaded (including app-wide resources in App.xaml). So I just created a new instance of MainViewModel in the share page's constructor, loaded only the things I need for the share to complete, save the information and call `ShareOperation.ReportCompleted`. This returns the user back to the app that is sharing.

I still haven't found a good solution for getting other resources in my ViewModel, but this works for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This indicates that the following line has not been executed:

```
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
```

This line will instruct the ServiceLocator class to use the SimpleIoc.Default instance as its ServiceLocator.Current. When you run your app as a Share target, the initialization is slightly different and probably the ViewModelLocator doesn't get initialized. You need to find a good location to perform the initialization before you use the ServiceLocator.

Cheers
Laurent

Comment: Laurent, I have found that the ViewModelLocator set in App.xaml doesn't instantiate in other scenarios as well. What happens if I just new up a ViewModelLocator in the OnActivated, will I get multiple instances of my MainViewModel, or will IOC keep it the same instance